# change vertical position of footer in scrlttr2 from KOMA

Tags: vertical-alignment, koma-script, scrlttr2

I have a document that uses KOMA script. It is a scrlttr2. I want to set a footer, which I did with

```
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{
  bla bla bla
}
```

Now the *bla bla* is a little bit longer, too long for the page. I’ve found that I can change the footer position with something called `firstfootvpos`.

## My question

Where do I have to put the `firstfootvpos`? I tried

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrlttr2}

\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{200mm}
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{
bla bla bla
…
```

which I’ve found somewhere in the net, but *it didn’t work* (i.e. `LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}`).

If I put it below `\begin{document}` then I get the error `You can't use '\spacefactor' in vertical mode.`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should read [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](http://goo.gl/HYwLd) However, KOMA-script should provide a user interface to manage `firstfootvpos` lenghts...

Comment: @Werner: That helped a lot. Latex is a strange chaos!

Answer (score 2):

If one understands what [`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/37568), then one can put the variable change everywhere before the document ends. So it should look like:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrlttr2}

\makeatletter
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{200mm}
\makeatother

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{
bla bla bla
…
```

Why? Well, seems that it’s because the @-letter has some strange extra behaviour on tex. That is how I understood it without being a tex-guru.

---

### Update

One can now directly use `\setplength{firstfootvpos}{200mm}` anywhere:

> Because I'm fed up with the complaining that @setplength doesn't work, there are now additionally \setplength, \newplength and \addtoplength.
> Note: This extension exists as of KOMA-Script 3.26.2980.

https://komascript.de/release3.26